# perl and php md5 file checksum doesn't match

Tags: php, perl, md5

i'm trying to get the checksum fore a binary file
running php's

```
$checksum =md5_file($fname)
```

and for perl

```
 use Digest::MD5;
 open FILE, "$fname";
 $ctx = Digest::MD5->new;
 $ctx->addfile(*FILE);
 $checksum = $ctx->hexdigest;
```

I get different results
interesting enough running it on a small text file returned the same checksum

Comment: have you confirmed that the two inputs are identical once they get into the respective language's innards, e.g. no line-ending translation taking place before being fed into the md5 core?

Answer (score 3):

With Perl, did you make sure that the file handle was in [binmode](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html) as [the documentation](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Digest-MD5/MD5.pm) suggests?

> In most cases you want to make sure that the $io_handle is in binmode before you pass it as argument to the addfile() method.

I modified the example from the documentation to match your example:

```
use Digest::MD5;
open (my $fh, '<', $fname) or die "Can't open '$fname': $!";
binmode ($fh);
my $checksum = Digest::MD5->new->addfile($fh)->hexdigest;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`binmode(FILE)`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html) after opening the file. If you still have differences with that change, then look at your PHP code because the updated Perl code produces the correct output:

```
$ perl dm.pl .bashrc
f5bb0773a3346814d978f9a155176d8e

$ md5sum .bashrc
f5bb0773a3346814d978f9a155176d8e *.bashrc
```